# Why autosize UITextview is not working in this case?

Tags: swift, uitextview

Autosize increase UITextview is not working, in this case, please help me.

[image]

This is my code for increase Textview:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
     constTextview.constant = textView.contentSize.height
}
```

> **constTextview** is Height Outlet for Textview height.

After pest 3 lines Textview inner scroll is not working. Please check GIF.

Comment: Check out my git repo on the same. It will help. https://github.com/rakeshashastri/resizing-textView-in-tableviewcell It is a really small and simple example.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri In your case, You provide a Programmatically constraint to TextView. Please give solution on my code.

Comment: If you went through the example properly and tried it, you would realize that it works for your case as well. Also, if anyone is supposed to help you, you need to provide more code. There is literally no mention about your cell layout. Just a constraint variable which from the name i assume is your textview height constraint.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - I have created Textview. and Provide fixed Height in the storyboard (constTextview.constant). This constant will increase in this method(textViewDidChange) as per Textview contentSize.  Copy 3 line text as per GIF and pest it into Textview.  Textview Scroll not working at that time.

Comment: Check the `textDidChange` method in my example and understand what it does. P.S - I did not downvote.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Okay, no problem I try your example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189888/discussion-between-parth-patel-and-rakesha-shastri).

Comment: I’m really sorry. I can’t join right now. I’m outside. All you need to do is layout the view again and update the table after changing the constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution working in my case:

> **constTextview** is Height constraint of my Textview.
>
> @IBOutlet var constTextview: NSLayoutConstraint!

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
     constTextview.constant = textView.contentSize.height
     textView.beginFloatingCursor(at: CGPoint.zero)
     textView.endFloatingCursor()
}
```